# What are the differences between Gallean's Return and Rise of the Elves?

Tags: version-differences, disciples-2

There are two versions available right now for the same price [Gallean's Return](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1640/Disciples_II_Galleans_Return/) and [Rise of the Elves](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1630/Disciples_II_Rise_of_the_Elves/) in Steam.

From description of Gallean's Return:

> Random map generator.
> Multiple resolution support.
> ...
> Support for large maps, 120x120 and 144x14

I want to play with these features, but I also want to have Elves as a playable race. Are these features included into Rise of the Elves?

I plan to play in hot-seat mode, so I don't care about single player campaigns